# "Jelly in a vise" meaning

Tags: meaning, proverbs, pro-verb-constructions

Jelly in a vise is a proverb mentioned in "Asian Figure" by W.S Merwin.
What does "Jelly" mean in this proverb? Does it mean gelatinous? Or the jelly that we eat?
What kind of clamp is a "Vise"?

Comment: Does it matter which type of jelly? You can google image search to find what a vise is. The meaning is clear, there's no idiom at use.

Comment: As a Brit, I'm finding the spelling "vise" really weird to look at. There are many American spellings that I am used to, but not that one. It's "vice" over here.

Comment: You might want to check out the exchange for [ell.se].

Comment: Americans, who spell 'vise' thus, also use the word 'jelly' for something that Brits call 'jam'. What Brits call 'jelly', Americans usually call "Jell-O", I think. Which makes this odd because jam is runny and cannot be placed in a vice, whereas you could put a block of jelly in a vice, and try to grip it, with results that Merwin's metaphor seems to envisage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a metaphor. A Jelly cannot remain intact when tightened in a vise. A [vise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vise) is like a clamp used to hold things firmly.

> **Vise** - 
> a tool with two parts that can be moved together by tightening a screw so that an object can be held firmly between them while it is being worked on

So to describe a very tight / tense situation this phrase can be used where the subject is in tight scrutiny / focus and cannot hold the pressure mounting on it.

> **Example usage -** "I literally felt like Jelly in a vise to have written the final exams without preparation"